# Objective-c proper delegation

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm new to objective-c and, maybe I haven't grassped the concept of delegation very clearly yet, but i hope to do it by using it. I'm trying to implement a delegation in my app.

Idea is that i have class `TableViewController` which has `NSMutableArray` used for `TableView` initialization. I need to reinitialize this Array from my `DropDown` class. I'v tried to do that using delegation but failed to do it yet, maybe there is something wrong with it. I could pass `TableViewController` to `DropDown` class and edit the table via object. But i'd like to get it done using delegation.

Here is my `TableViewController.h`

```
@protocol TableViewControllerdelegate;
@interface TableViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate>
{
    ControllerType controllerType;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *dataArray;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *imageArray;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil andType:(ControllerType)type;
- (void)sendSMS: (NSString *) sms;

@end;
```

Here is my `DropDown.h`

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
@interface DropDownExample : UITableViewController <VPPDropDownDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate> {
@private
    VPPDropDown *_dropDownSelection;
    VPPDropDown *_dropDownSelection1;
    VPPDropDown *_dropDownSelection2;
    VPPDropDown *_dropDownSelection3;
    VPPDropDown *_dropDownSelection4;
    VPPDropDown *_dropDownDisclosure;
    VPPDropDown *_msg;
    VPPDropDown *_dropDownCustom;

    NSIndexPath *_ipToDeselect;
}
+ (bool) uncheck:(UITableViewCell *) cell andData:(NSString *) data;
- (void)reloadData;
@end
```

And this is how i try to edit my tableview object array

```
            TableViewController *newControll = (TableViewController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
            NSMutableArray *arrayWithInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:AMLocalizedString(@"Status", nil),AMLocalizedString(@"Call", nil),AMLocalizedString(@"Location", nil),AMLocalizedString(@"Control", nil),AMLocalizedString(@"Sim", nil),AMLocalizedString(@"Object", nil),AMLocalizedString(@"Info", nil),nil];
            newControll.dataArray = arrayWithInfo;
            [arrayWithInfo release];
            [newControll.tableView reloadData];
```

I get it running, but it get's `'-[AppDelegate setDataArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`  after reaching this code.

Comment: Please show to definition of the `VPPDropDownDelegate`.

Comment: It is used in for another delegation (not constructed by me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I am not sure if I got this right but it finally clicked for me what delegation is and why I need it. Hopefully you'll understand too once you read through my scenario.

### History

Previously, in my UITabBar app, I wanted to show a custom form view overlaid on top of my view controller to enter name and email.

Later I also needed to show the same custom overlay on top of another view controller on another tab.

At the time I didn't really know what delegation was for, so the first method I used to tackle this problem was NSNotificationCenter. I duplicated the same code to my second view controller and hooked it up to a button press event.

On pressing a button on the second view controller on another tab, it certainly showed my custom overlay, just like my first view controller.

However, this is where the problem starts.

### The Problem

I needed to close my custom form view. So using NSNotificationCenter, I posted a notification and the listener callback method for the notification was told to close my custom view.

The problem was, using NSNotificationCenter, all listeners both in my first tab and my second tab responded to the posted notification and as a result, instead of closing just the custom form view overlaid on top of my second view controller, it closed ALL my custom view, regardless of where the custom view was opened from.

What I wanted was when I tap on the "X" button to close my custom form view, I only want it to close it for that single instance of the custom view, not all the other ones I had opened.

### The Solution: Delegation

This is where it finally clicked for me - delegation.

With delegation, I tell each instance of my custom form view who the delegate was, and if I was to tap on the "X" button to close my custom view, it only close it for that single instance that was opened, all the other view controllers were untouched.

### Some Code

Right, down to some code.

Not sure if this is the best way to do it (correct me if I am wrong) but this is how I do it:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Custom Form class .h file
// ------------------------------------------------------------

@protocol MyCustomFormDelegate <NSObject>

// if you don't put a @optional before any method, then they become required
// in other words, you must implement these methods
-(void)sendButtonPressed;
-(void)closeButtonPressed;

// example: these two methods here does not need to be implemented
@optional
-(void)optionalMethod1;
-(void)optioinalMethod2;

@end

@interface MyCustomFormView : UIView
{
    ...
    id<MyCustomFormDelegate> delegate;
}

...
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<MyCustomFormDelegate> delegate;

@end


// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Custom Form class .m file
// ------------------------------------------------------------

...

@implementation TruckPickerView

@synthesize delegate;

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if(self)
    {
        ...

        [btnSend addTarget:self selector:@selector(sendEmail) forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        ...

        [btnClose addTarget:self selector:@selector(closeForm) forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)sendEmail
{
    // code sends email

    ...

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // tell the delegate to execute the delegate callback method
    //
    // note: the implementation will be defined in the 
    // view controller (see below)
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    [delegate sendButtonPressed];
}

-(void)closeForm
{
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // tell the delegate to execute the delgate callback method
    //
    // note: the implementation will be defined in the 
    // view controller (see below)
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    [delegate closeButtonPressed];
}



// ------------------------------------------------------------
// view controller .h file
// ------------------------------------------------------------

#import "MyCustomFormView.h"

// conform to our delegate protocol
@interface MyViewController <MyCustomFormDelegate>
{
    ...

    // create a single instance of our custom view
    MyCustomFormView *customForm;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MyCustomFormView *customForm;


// ------------------------------------------------------------
// view controller .m file
// ------------------------------------------------------------

@synthesize customForm;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    customForm = [[MyCustomFormView alloc] initWithFrame:....];

    // tell our custom form this view controller is the delegate
    customForm.delegate = self;

    // only show the custom form when user tap on the designated button
    customForm.hidden = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:customForm];
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    ...
    [customForm release];
    [super dealloc];
}

// helper method to show and hide the custom form
-(void)showForm
{
    customForm.hidden = NO;
}

-(void)hideForm
{
    customForm.hidden = YES;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// implement the two defined required delegate methods
// ------------------------------------------------------------
-(void)sendButtonPressed
{
    ...

    // email has been sent, do something then close 
    // the custom form view afterwards

    ...

    [self hideForm];
}

-(void)closeButtonPressed
{
    // Don't send email, just close the custom form view 
    [self hideForm];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get that error, because (as the error says) you're sending a `setDataArray:` message to your app delegate (the AppDelegate class).

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

This will return the delegate of you app. There are a couple of ways to find out which class is your app's delegate, but usually it's called AppDelegate (as in your case) and it's implementing the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol too.

You can't simply cast that to a completely different class. If your app delegate has an ivar or property of type `TableViewController` you have to use accessors to get it. If it's a property, you can use the dot notation. If it's an ivar, you can either implement a getter method that returns the ivar, or make it a property instead.

```
// assuming your app delegate has a TableViewController property called myTableViewController.
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
TableViewController *tableViewController = appDelegate.myTableViewController;
```

This will fix the error, but your use of the delegate pattern is wrong too. I don't see where you're using any custom delegates. You forward declare a `TableViewControllerdelegate` protocol, but I don't see any declaration of it, or I don't see where you're trying to use it.